# PHPUnit dumps response unexpectedly

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I have the following very simple test:

```
use AppBundle\Controller\AdminFriendController;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class AdminFriendTest extends WebTestCase {
    public function testFriendEntry() {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/Admin/Friend/Enter');        
    }
}
```

When it runs, the output of the test is the entire page from the GET request at /Admin/Friend/Enter. I was expecting just the phpUnit header and a "R" for risky test since I have no assertions. I have also tried this with the entire test written, and I get the same result. I have removed all other code here that does not change the result to simplify the question.

I expected PHPUnit to suppress all that HTML and only provide me with the useful nugget of information. Can anyone tell me why this is producing so much output?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe an `echo` in die controller action?

Comment: Maybe this route requires authorization? Are you sure that this content belongs to that route? Please paste the entire output of phpunit.